# Ruby gsub doesn't escape single-quotes

Tags: ruby, escaping, gsub

I don't understand what is going on here. How should I feed gsub to get the string "Yaho\'o"?

```
>> "Yaho'o".gsub("Y", "\\Y")
=> "\\Yaho'o"
>> "Yaho'o".gsub("'", "\\'")
=> "Yahooo"
```

Comment: This is one of the weirder things I've seen.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

\' means $' which is everything after the match.
Escape the \ again and it works

```
"Yaho'o".gsub("'", "\\\\'")
```

Comment: ruby 1.9.3
`"Yaho'o".gsub("'", "\\\\'")
=> "Yaho\\'o"`

Comment: @AdrienSchuler It does work, IRB displays a double backslash so you can see that it's escaped. `"Yaho'o".gsub("'", "\\\\'").length => 7`

Comment: Where is this documented?

Answer (score 2):

```
"Yaho'o".gsub("'", "\\\\'")
```

Because you're escaping the escape character as well as escaping the single quote.

Answer (score 1):

This will also do it, and it's a bit more readable:

```
def escape_single_quotes(str)
  str.gsub(/'/) { |x| "\\#{x}" }
end
```

If you want to escape both a single-quote and a backslash, so that you can embed that string in a double-quoted ruby string, then the following will do that for you:

```
def escape_single_quotes_and_backslash(str)
  str.gsub(/\\|'/) { |x| "\\#{x}" }
end
```

Comment: I used the top one, and it worked perfectly.  exactly what I needed.