# Escaping Apostrophes Using Gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I'm working in Ruby and I'm trying to escape `'` characters to `\'` so that I can use them in SQL. I'm trying to use `gsub`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
"this doesn't work".gsub /'/, '\\'' #=> "this doesnt workt work"
"this doesn't work".gsub /'/, '\\\'' #=> "this doesnt workt work"
"this doesn't work".gsub /'/, '\\\\'' #=> "this doesn\\'t work"
"this doesn't work".gsub /'/, '\\\\\'' #=> "this doesn\\'t work"
```

I don't know if `gsub` is even the right method to be using, so I'm willing to try almost anything that gets the results I'm looking for.

Comment: Don't stop at four. Go for five. Actually, four should return an error. Also, notice that in order for ruby to show (inspect) the result within double quotation, it will escape a backslash. You might not be noticing that you already got it.

Comment: @sawa Thanks. You're right, I didn't even notice that I got it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else had this very issue, due to a special meaning/interpretation in Ruby's regex.

> \' means $' which is everything after
>   the match. Escape the \ again and it
>   works

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180322/ruby-gsub-doesnt-escape-single-quotes).

Does this work?

```
"this doesn't work".gsub /'/, '\\\\\'' => "this doesn\\'t work"
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it double-escapes the `'` to `\\'`. I'm looking for a `\'`.

Comment: Dang it. I forgot that when the result is displayed in double quotes it shows it escaped. When the program wrote to a file and I opened it, everything is correct. I guess I'm just an idiot.

Comment: No worries. Threw me off too. So long as the code works, that is the point, yes? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the \ and the '.
When you need the ' in the result, why not define the result with "

```
puts "this doesn't work".gsub /'/, "\\\\'" #=> "this doesn\'t work"
```

\ must be escaped anyway.