# Why does String#gsub double content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

```
s = "#main= 'quotes'
s.gsub "'", "\\'" # => "#main= quotes'quotes"
```

This seems to be wrong, I expect to get `"#main= \\'quotes\\'"`

when I don't use escape char, then it works as expected.

```
s.gsub "'", "*" # => "#main= *quotes*"
```

So there must be something to do with escaping.

Using ruby 1.9.2p290

I need to replace single quotes with back-slash and a quote.

Even more inconsistencies:

```
"\\'".length # => 2
"\\*".length # => 2

# As expected
"'".gsub("'", "\\*").length # => 2
"'a'".gsub("'", "\\*") # => "\\*a\\*" (length==5)

# WTF next:
"'".gsub("'", "\\'").length # => 0

# Doubling the content?
"'a'".gsub("'", "\\'") # => "a'a" (length==3)
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499443/escaping-apostrophes-using-gsub and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180322/ruby-gsub-doesnt-escape-single-quotes . I had to combine the [ruby] [gsub] tags, then look at the "FAQ" tag.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the librarian work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're getting tripped up by the specialness of [`\'` inside a regular expression replacement string](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UM):

> **`\0`, `\1`, `\2`, ... `\9`, `\&`, `` \` ``, `\'`, `\+`**
>   Substitutes the value matched by the nth grouped subexpression, or by the entire match, pre- or postmatch, or the highest group.

So when you say `"\\'"`, the double `\\` becomes just a single backslash and the result is `\'` but that means "The string to the right of the last successful match." If you want to replace single quotes with escaped single quotes, you need to escape more to get past the specialness of `\'`:

```
s.gsub("'", "\\\\'")
```

Or avoid the toothpicks and use the block form:

```
s.gsub("'") { |m| '\\' + m }
```

You would run into similar issues if you were trying to escape backticks, a plus sign, or even a single digit.

The overall lesson here is to prefer the [block form of `gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) for anything but the most trivial of substitutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It definitely clears the things. I just wonder what the substitutions `\&, \`, \', \+` mean? I can't remember I've see them used anywhere.

Comment: @Dmytrii: Looking at the global variable versions of those might help (http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#19). I don't know of a good authoritative online reference for Ruby's regexes.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = "#main = 'quotes'

s.gsub "'", "\\\\'"
```

Since `\`it's `\\`equivalent if you want to get a double backslash you have to put four of ones.

Comment: I don't want double backslash - only one. That's why I escape one slash and add quote. The `"\\'".length == 2` which is correct. `gsub` gets it wrong by doubling the content.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the \ as well:

```
s.gsub "'", "\\\\'"
```

Outputs

```
"#main= \\'quotes\\'"
```

A good explanation found on an outside forum:

> The key point to understand IMHO is that a backslash is special in
>   replacement strings.  So, whenever one wants to have a literal
>   backslash in a replacement string one needs to escape it and hence
>   have [two] backslashes.  Coincidentally a backslash is also special in a
>   string (even in a single quoted string).  So you need two levels of
>   escaping, makes 2 * 2 = 4 backslashes on the screen for one literal
>   replacement backslash.

[source](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Ruby/36273379/gsub-and-backslashes.aspx)

Comment: But it is already escaped - the string `"\\"` should return a single slash. So then `"\\'"` returns string with length equal to 2: first is the slash, second is the quote. It is messed up in gsub because it doubles the content (why?).

Comment: Additionally `.gsub("'", "\\*")` works as expected, which is even more inconsistent.

Comment: The problem is that [`\'` has a special meaning](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UM) in a regex substitution, this somewhat obscure feature is around mostly for historic reasons.