# Replacing ' by \' in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have one ruby script which parses one CSV and generates some XML files.
In this process, I am stuck at changing

`it's free`

to

`it\'s free`

Seems to be a trivial task, but I couldn't complete it.

Tried below

```
gsub("'","\'")
```

Comment: `CSV.generate(headers: true) { |csv| csv << [r1c1, r1c2]; csv << [r2c1, r2c2]  }`, you can create csv content by above `r1c1` is nothing but string content of first ro first column

Comment: @mu-is-too-short solution mention here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7074726/1677824 is not working for me. It prints extra \ in result ```source.gsub("'","\\\\'")
=> "It\\'s Free"```

Comment: @Akhil That's because you're looking at the result in `irb` which uses `#inspect` to display the value of the last expression. Look at `puts source.gsub("'","\\\\'").inspect` and `puts source.gsub("'","\\\\'")` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thanks @mu-is-too-short it worked !!