# How to modify string in Ruby such that all instances of apostrophe are replaced with backslash apostrophe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, escaping

I want a string such as "This is Bob's sentence" to be modified to be "This is Bob\'s sentence"

My research seems to indicate that the following should work

`"This is Bob's sentence".gsub("'", "\\'")`

But the result I get is

> "this is Bobs messages message"

I'm doing this in a rails app.  Perhaps something else in the app is causing the issue?  If you could please inform me of a ruby method which you know should work I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this just [**Why does String#gsub double content?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7074337/479863) in disguise?

Comment: thanks @muistooshort.  So, it looks like you can do `"This is Bob's sentence".gsub("'", '\\\\\'')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the capture like this:

```
puts "This is Bob's sentence".gsub(/(\w\')/, '\1\\')
This is Bob'\s sentence
```

You capture in a regular expression what's inside parens `()` and then you can modify it with `\1`.  You can have more than one capture group, they are numbered in order as they appear.

For more see similar example https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#gsub

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  However, this doesn't seem to work for me when the string is in a variable:
`foo = "This is Bob's sentence"`
`foo.gsub(/(\w\')/, '\1\\')`
=> "This is Bob'\\s sentence"

Comment: Plus, I need the backslash in front of the apostrophe.

Comment: Ruby console will escape the backslash but the string actually is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Per thread referenced by mu is too short

`"This is Bob's sentence".gsub("'", "\\\\\'")`

Comment: Yeah, it is a little horrific when everyone wants to use the backslash and you end up escaping your escaped escapes.

Answer (score 0):

This is annoying, but here's a solution that works:

```
sentence = "This is Bob's sentence"
sent_arr = sentence.gsub("'", "\\").split('')
sent_arr.each_index.select{|i| sent_arr[i] == "\\"}.each{|i| sent_arr.insert(i+1, "'") }
final_sentence = sent_arr.join
puts final_sentence
```

Basically:

1. Replace `"'"` with `"\\"` (which is counted as only one index), make an array out of it.
2. Find each index of `"\\"` in the array, insert a `"'"` at the position just after each.
3. Join the array into a string.

Even though the variable will seem to have two instances of the backslash (`\\`), when you `puts` the variable, you'll see that it only has one.

(Ironically, even StackOverflow escapes the backslashes in this response if you don't put it in code form... I had to put 3 backslashes to make it look like 2!)