# Escaping Apostrophes from Word with Gsub

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use gsub to parse out this: `’` which is an apostrophe from Microsoft Word. Here's what I"m doing

```
row['Content'] = row['Content'].gsub(/’/, '-' )
```

gives me the error

```
    reader.rb:18: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
    reader.rb:18: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
    reader.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
    row['Content'] = row['Content'].gsub(/’/, '-' )
```

I've tried all sorts of variations and looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499443/escaping-apostrophes-using-gsub), but am at loss. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `row['Content'}` - you should be closing with a square bracket rather than a brace (`row['Content']`)

Comment: good catch. I don't know why, but I didn't copy/past it. I fixed it and it's now accurate to the code I'm using.

Comment: could you edit the question to include the full error backtrace?  I'm not getting the same problem when I try to run it

Comment: What *is* that character you're trying to `gsub` out?  I'm copying and pasting from your code example and having no problem, is it a special unicode character?

Comment: And if it is, you may need to add an encoding specifier at the top of the file, such as `# encoding: UTF-8`

Comment: Agreed, this is probably an encoding issue—especially if the OP is using Ruby 1.9.

Comment: I added `# encoding: UTF-8` and the error changed to `reader.rb:20:in 'gsub': incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)` this only happens when the `’` is in the CSV

Comment: Encoding issues really make my brain hurt!  If it's just that the regex can't deal with differing encodings, you could try a string gsub: `gsub("’", '-')`

Comment: Yeah, mine too. I tried the string gsub too with no luck. Oh well. I'll keep working at it.

Comment: My only other idea would be to `.encode('utf8')` the string coming from word before you try and do the gsub.

Comment: If that doesn't help, perhaps you can indicate in the question somehow, exactly what that character is so others can help better

Comment: I updated the question. It's just an apostrophe from microsoft word.