# Unexpected behavior with ruby gsub and '\\'

Tags: ruby

I want to escape single quotes using ruby [`#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) but I observe strange behavior.

```
"My 'message'".gsub("'", "\\'")
-> "My message'message"
```

I expected to get `"My \'message\'"`. Why is `message` repeated?

I can workaround that using `"My 'message'".gsub("'") { "\\'" }` but I'd like to know what happens with `"My 'message'".gsub("'", "\\'")`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180322/ruby-gsub-doesnt-escape-single-quotes has the answer: "\' means $' which is everything after the match.". What should I do with this question, should I delete it?

Comment: I'd leave it alone now that it is marked as a duplicate. This particular problem is really hard to search for so maybe a duplicate will make the searching easier.

Comment: @muistooshort Ok, I'll not delete this question then. Thanks.

Comment: _Sidenote_: since it’s 2015 all around, one might use typograhically correct single quotes `‘` and `’` instead of escaping apostrophs.

Comment: @mudasobwa tell that to our customers :)