# Unexpected behavior of backreferences in Ruby String#gsub

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

So I think this is weird:

```
"x'y".gsub("'", "\\'")
=> "xyy"
```

The variant,

```
'x"y'.gsub('"', "\'")
=> "x'y"
```

Works just fine.

Either it's a bug (unlikely) or it's something with how Ruby handles backreferences that I don't understand. Can anyone explain what happens in the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\'` means `$'` which is everything after the match.

(or)
 `\'` in a gsub replacement means **"part of the string after the match."**

 Escape the `\` again and it works,

```
"x'y".gsub("'", "\\\\'")
```

you can also use  `%q delimiters` here,

```
"x'y".gsub("'", %q(\\\'))  

//(IRB uses \\ to make an escape-\ visible)
```

Referred from [Gsub wierd behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180322/ruby-gsub-doesnt-escape-single-quotes)

Comment: Do you know if this is documented anywhere? The documentation for [sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) even says `[..] but is actually not a pattern capture group e.g. "\'", then it will have to be preceded by two backslashes like so "\\'"`

Comment: Me too didn't get the correct documentation of it any where, but as we need to escape the escape character and single quote so shld use 4 back slashes there.